# How to handle transaction involving Spring message/JMS and Database

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-jms

I have a method that get an invoice and it creates XML and send that XML to a JMS queue and then save the invoice to DB with updated status like 'invoiced'. Below is pseudo code that involves Spring and Hibernate.  My question is: Is the failure in hibernate save rollsback Jms sending.or if JMS send failed, how can I roll back saving invoice status? is this comes under distributed transaction management. What are the transactional cases involved here. Thanks.

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.Required)    
 void processInvoices(invoice ){
           String xml = createXML(invoice);
           messageService.sendInvoice(xml );
           invoice.setStatus("invoiced");
           save(invoice);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge and what I understand from your question you want to synchronize hibernate and JMS transaction, For doing this you will need to use JTA to manage transactions across the the both Hibernate and JMS

Read More @ [Spring synchronising Hibernate and JMS transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799711/spring-synchronising-hibernate-and-jms-transactions#answer-10800431)

Comment: Thanks, for the quick reply. This statement from the link you mentioned " When I call send() on the JmsTemplate, the message is not immediately sent, but rather the JMS session is committed with the Hibernate session as the method returns.", for spring @transactional holds true to my case, right? i.e When my invoice is saved then only the xml will be on queue, right?